# SWIG syntax error when defining bool

Tags: java, c, boolean, swig

The following module fails to be processed by SWIG with the error message "example.i:2: Error: Syntax error in input(1)"

```
%module example
typedef unsigned char bool;
bool isEven(int number);
```

When changing `bool` to `boll` everything works fine. It seems that SWIG treats bool as a builtin type in C. However only _Bool is a builtin type in C99 and bool is not defined unless including `stdbool.h`

I have a large interface that I need to wrap for java which contains the following typedef:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef unsigned char bool;
#endif
```

I could get around the problems by adding

```
#define __cplusplus
```

to my SWIG module file before including the header defining the interface.
However in this case including cpointer.i does not work anymore (Error: Missing identifier for #ifdef which occurs for every line of cpointer.i containing `#ifdef __cplusplus`)

Any suggestions on how I can use my interface header file without changing it (i.e. without removing my bool typedef) and still being able to use cpointer.i?

Comment: It seems that the name bool is already defined. For example it can be a macro. So you need to check what is the bool. Instead of the bla...bla..bla.. you should show the error message.

Comment: I don't include anything, so there is no code that can define the name bool. When I run SWIG on example.i which contains only the 3 lines from above I get "example.i:2: Error: Syntax error in input(1)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `bool` is really not defined in your case, there should be no problem renaming it to something else with a macro in the SWIG interface file, i.e., do:

```
%module example
#define bool uchar_bool
typedef unsigned char bool;
bool isEven(int number);
```